# How to find the average of a subset of cells in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have the results of an experiment in which participants give a rating from 0-9 (dependent variable) in 5 different conditions (independent variable), in a random order.
I get numeric arrays similar to this

```
ratings = [ 5 7 2 4 8 7 6 3 5 6]   
level   = [ 1 5 3 3 2 4 5 4 1 2]
```

I would like to find the average ratings for each level of my experiment, so i can eventually plot as a scatter plot. Could anyone point me in the direction of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compute the mean rating for each level, you can use `accumarray` to do this. What `accumarray` will do is group ratings by their corresponding value in `level`. Then it will apply the function specified as the fourth input to each of these groups. In your case, we use `@mean` to simply compute the mean of all ratings which share the same `level` value.

```
accumarray(level(:), ratings(:), [], @mean);

%        5
%        7
%        3
%        5
%      6.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the `accumarray` solution. But just for variety, this also works:

```
result = nonzeros(sparse(level,1,ratings))./nonzeros(sparse(level,1,1));
```

Comment: You're on a `sparse` kick lately! Clever.

Comment: @Suever You had already taken the `accumarray` approach, so.. :-)